# How do you search through a directory and take actions?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking to make a batch file which will sift through a directory full of computer backups. The file format is "computername-date." Since I know the computer name is static, I need to find and take that directory so I can restore it's contents.

I never realized that for loops are so foreign from what I play with in other languages, so I find myself getting nowhere anytime soon.

```
REM First mount the drive that contains the backed up files
net use P: \\DC1\Shared\1Backups 

REM Get the computer's name so we know what PC backup to use.
set SaveDirectory=%computername%

REM For each folder in the directory, do this when the computer name is found. 
FOR /R "P:\" %%G in (%SaveDirectory%*) DO (
    REM Restore files
    echo found it.
    REM Copy subdirectories into User Folder
    mkdir P:\UGH
)

REM Dismount drive
```

The problem with what I have now is that when I run the code, the DO never runs. It should find that there is a folder called "INTERN-6.21.2019" by searching "INTERN*"

My impression of the for statement may be wrong. I need it to search through the P:/ Directory, not the subfolders. Compare the folder names to the SavedDirectory, then do something when they match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the command `FOR /?` to read about the `/R` switch. It is designed to walk the directory tree. That is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've normally had good results with using CALL statements to invoke a subroutine rather than running items inside ( ).

The trick here is that you need to pass arguments to the the subroutine. Typically you'd pass the variable(s) you use in your FOR statement.  These are referenced using %1 (or %1 %2 %3 if you have multiple things to pass) because these act like command line arguments. To exit the subroutine you then jump to EOF which then returns control to your FOR loop.  After your FOR loop, don't forget to jump over your subroutine or you'll execute it again.  In the example below I jump to :end, but you certainly could jump to somewhere else to do more things.

So using this methodology, your code might be like this:

```
set SaveDirectory=%computername%

FOR /R "P:\" %%G in (%SaveDirectory%*) DO CALL :process %%G
Goto :end

:process
REM Processing goes here
goto :end

:end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This might get you going. This will find the "newest" directory. It is not clear from the question exactly what is to be copied and to where.

```
SET "MOSTRECENT=unknown"

FOR /F "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B /A:D /O:D "P:\%COMPUTERNAME%*"') DO (
    SET "MOSTRECENT=%%~fd"
)

ECHO The most recent backup is "%MOSTRECENT%"

IF EXIST "MOSTRECENT" (COPY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon my understanding of what you're trying to do, *copy a network directory named with the computername and a datestring, (with todays date), to another location*:

```bat
@PushD "\\DC1\Shared\1Backups" || GoTo :EOF 
@For /F "EOL=DTokens=1-3" %%A In (
    'WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year'
)Do @For /F Tokens^=* %%D In ("%%C"
)Do @XCopy "%COMPUTERNAME%-%%B.%%A.%%D" "P:\UGH\" /H /R /K /Y>NUL 2>&1
@PopD
```